# Issue with Xamarin Sliders and restoring application state

Tags: c#, xamarin, slider, state

New to Xamarin and the whole mobile platform stuff, also been a while since I've developed.  But, that being said, I think I've gotten pretty far with this except for current issue.

I have a grid form that has multiple slider controls on it all set from 0 to 15.  They work great, the problem is when I try to save and restore my application properties.  Saving and restoring the first slider is fine (along with other controls).  When I add second or third they all get the value of the last slider. Example - if Slider 1 = 5, Slider 2 = 10 and Slider 3 = 15 on start after reading properties all sliders have a value of 15.

I've checked my variables, control names and properties multiple times.  The names are different for each slider.

```
const string p1s1secscore = "0";
const string p1s2secscore = "0";
    
public string P1S1SecScore { get; set; }
public string P1S2SecScore { get; set; }
    
    
if (Properties.ContainsKey(p1s1secscore))
{
   P1S1SecScore = (string)Properties[p1s1secscore];
}
if (Properties.ContainsKey(p1s2secscore))
{
     P1S2SecScore = (string)Properties[p1s2secscore];
}
    
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing(); 
   p1S1Slider.Value = ToInt32((Application.Current as App).P1S1SecScore);
   p1S2Slider.Value = ToInt32((Application.Current as App).P1S2SecScore);
}
```

I even explicitly set two of the value (below) to test. On restore both sliders have 15 for a value.

```
   (Application.Current as App).P1S1SecScore = "10";
   (Application.Current as App).P1S2SecScore = "15";
```

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

you are using these as the keys for your Properties dictionary

```
const string p1s1secscore = "0";
const string p1s2secscore = "0";
```

and both are the same value `0`, so this

```
if (Properties.ContainsKey(p1s1secscore))
{
   P1S1SecScore = (string)Properties[p1s1secscore];
}
if (Properties.ContainsKey(p1s2secscore))
{
     P1S2SecScore = (string)Properties[p1s2secscore];
}
```

will always retrieve the same key from your Dictionary

Comment: Yes I am, I just figured out a different way of declaring things (posted) and it is working great.

Comment: Jason - Oh, I see what you are saying.  Thanks will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, found a different example and it working like a champ.  Using this type of structure for all my properties:

```
if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("P1S1Scoring"))
{
   p1S1Score.Text = Application.Current.Properties["P1S1Scoring"].ToString();
   p1S1Slider.Value = ToInt32(p1S1Score.Text);
}
```

I guess this is explicitly setting the property without using the "const" and overridden constructors in app.xmal.cs

Comment: there is nothing wrong with what you were doing originally, you just need to be sure that each const is set to a unique value